# How to customize UITableViewCell's insertion and deletion control?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image: Screenshot]

I have these insertion/deletion controls enabled by default for all the cells as the picture above. I'd like to know if there's a way to customize the graphics of those controls (change the images of plus/minus sign)? Is using custom cell the only way? I'd prefer a simpler method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be quite simple. What I did was to set cell editing style to none, create a button with the custom images and use target-action to trigger

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: